# Can I use jquery load to call a PHP function?

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure what the best way to handle this is but here is what I'm trying to do.  After a user deletes a photo I need to update my two divs with new stats and a new table.  This is done initially by calling two functions.  Can I call these PHP functions with jquery somehow or is there a better way?

Here is what my current code snippet looks like:

```
<?php 
include('header.php');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.image_result li').click(function() {
        var imgInfo = $(this).attr('id').split(':');

        if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this image?')) {
            $.post('delete_image.php?image_id=' + imgInfo[0] + '&user_id=' + imgInfo[1], function(data) {

            // How can I update both divs (imageStats, and imageTable) by calling my two PHP functions?

            });
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div id="imageStats" ><?php echo get_image_stats(); ?></div>
<div id="imageTable" ><?php get_user_images(); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file that displays only the stuff output by the functions, for example:

**ajax.php**

```
// Include or require the file that contains your functions HERE

switch($_GET['action']) {

    case 'get_stats':
        echo get_image_stats();
        break;

    case 'get_images':
        get_user_images();
        break;
}
```

**JS**

```
$.post('delete_image.php?image_id=' + imgInfo[0] + '&user_id=' + imgInfo[1], function(data) {

    $('#imageStats').load('new_php_file.php?action=get_stats');
    $('#imageTable').load('new_php_file.php?action=get_images');;
});
```

**NOTE:** There are many ways of solving your specific problem. This is only one of countless implementations, but it should give you enough food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is call your PHP methods: `get_image_stats()` and `get_user_images()` and send their output back when the `delete_image.php` script is called from the jquery ajax post method.

Assuming `get_image_stats()` returns an alphanumeric string, `get_user_images()` returns a  complete HTML table and there are no "|" characters in either, what I would do is concatenate the output of `get_image_stats()` and `get_user_images()` with a “|” and echo it out `delete_image.php`.

On the success of a post, I would split the data back and update the stats and images like this:

```
var resp = data.split("|");
$('#imageStats').html(resp[0]);
$('#imageTable').html(resp[1]);
```

I recommend this approach because I think it will cause the least change to your existing code structure.

Comment: The only issue I have at this point is that I loose my click event after the new table is loaded...

Comment: Please edit the question and add the output of the two PHP functions i.e. the new stats and the new table.